# How to programmatically register a custom URL scheme?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, info.plist

Is it possible to add/remove custom URL schemes for my application while it's running? Right now the CFBundleURLSchemes property is set in Info.plist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this discussion on Cocoa Dev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DynamiclyRegisteringDocumentTypes) the answer is no, custom URL schemes can't be registered programmatically.  You must specify them in `Info.plist`. (but using `LSRegisterURL`, you *can* ask Launch Services to reload your application's `Info.plist` if you programmatically change it.  But that's ugly.).

Comment: The link is 404

Answer (score 1):

Launch Services will do that. Have a look at the [Launch Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999) and the [Launch Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000998) for details.

(Edit: Launch Services is what you want, but the function I mentioned was for changing the *default* handler.)