# Programmatically open Mac App Store

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mac-app-store

I am trying to programmatically open the Mac App Store in a custom Mac App. I started with the link below.

```
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds/id403961173?mt=12
```

I tried the following code, however it opens the browser rather than the Mac App Store.

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds/id403961173?mt=12"]];
```

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

URLs of this pattern open up the Mac App Store:

```
macappstore://itunes.apple.com/app/id403961173?mt=12
```

So in your case:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:@"macappstore://itunes.apple.com/app/id403961173?mt=12"]];
```

will open the MAS and load the product page associated with id #403961173 (here: Angry Birds).

To just load the MAS, with no particular product page use this URL:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:@"macappstore://itunes.apple.com/"]];
```

Comment: Indeed it is. :) It's called a [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme), btw. ;) You can even [register your own for your app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463998/how-to-programmatically-register-a-custom-url-scheme) Particularly handy for incorporating bookmarklet support. ;)

Comment: Regexident, This method do not work under sandbox, you will get "deny file-write-data /Applications/App Store.app"

Comment: @DavidL: yes, that warning is during debug only now under Xcode 4.5.2

Comment: Cool; for merely launching/activating the MAS it seems that `macappstore://` or even just `macappstore:` is sufficient (as of at least OS X 10.8.3).

Comment: Is there a way to open a specific developer page listing all of the developers apps using this approach?

Comment: I'm for almost 4 years searching answers for this question and still could not find a code that works.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to show the updates page you can use this URL:
macappstore://showUpdatesPage

Answer (score 0):

open the webpage in a UIWebView. the webview will then open itunes, or at least ask to open itunes.

that may be iphone specific. but whatever the WebView is for mac.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"/Applications/App Store.app"]
```

Comment: This will only open the MAS. But what it won't allow you is to choose a product page to open it with. That's where the URL scheme comes into play.

Comment: Though if you want to open a specific app in the App store, then [Regexident's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656746/programmatically-open-mac-app-store/5656762#5656762) is better.