# Add URL Scheme Programmatically in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsurl

I am search out the new thing. 
Is it possible to add the `URL Schemes` Programmatically in the app? 
The scenario is like User will get one key & I want to add it in `Info.plist` as a **URL** Schemes.

Is it Possible? The solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463998/how-to-programmatically-register-a-custom-url-scheme

Comment: @iPatel that link relates to OS X, not iOS.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? were you able to modify the URL Schemas programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

Hate to give bad news, but no you cannot, you must specify them in the Info.plist